# Can a formula cell reference be a variable cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

Assuming I insert every day some rows into Sheet1, this formula stops working and I have to manually edit every day --- can the reference to Cell A2 and Cell E2 be a variable that remains hardcoded as for example inserting 4 rows both became A6 and E6 and the value totals are all wrong until I manually change to A2 and E2 from A6 and E6:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER({WEEKDAY(Sheet1!A2:A),Sheet1!E2:E},ISNUMBER(Sheet1!E2:E),Sheet1!E2:E>0),"SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1), SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC LABEL Col1 'Day', COUNT(Col1) 'Count by Day', SUM(Col2) 'Sum by Day'"))
```

Can A2 be some pointer to a cell that has the text "A2" and it always stays as A2 in the formula -- same question for E2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned:

> Can A2 be some pointer to a cell that has the text "A2" and it always stays as A2 in the formula -- same question for E2 ?

You do not need to reference a pointer to an extra cell.

What you are looking for is the **[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)** function.

You can replace your ranges
`Sheet1!A2:A` and `Sheet1!E2:E` with
`INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2"&":A")` and `INDIRECT("Sheet1!E2"&":E")`

Comment: This gives a FORMULA PARSE ERROR .. =ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER({WEEKDAY(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2"&":A")),
   INDIRECT("Sheet1!E2"&":E"),
   ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!E2"&":E")),
   INDIRECT("Sheet1!E2"&":E")>0),
   "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1), SUM(Col2) 
   GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC LABEL Col1 'Day', 
   COUNT(Col1) 'Count by Day', 
   SUM(Col2) 'Sum by Day' 
   format Col1 'dddd'   "))

Comment: You **forgot** a `}` before the `ISNUMBER`. Your formula should be `=ArrayFormula(QUERY(FILTER({WEEKDAY(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2"&":A")),INDIRECT("Sheet1!E2"&":E")},ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!E2"&":E")),INDIRECT("Sheet1!E2"&":E")>0),"SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1), SUM(Col2) where Col1 is not null GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC LABEL Col1 'Day', COUNT(Col1) 'Count by Day', SUM(Col2) 'Sum by Day' format Col1 'dddd'"))`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. I had a look at your test sheet. Out of curiosity. Why is column `Sheet1!A` formatted as `Plain text` and not as `Date time` as it should be?